# Understanding an Axon library's Java Idiom involving Interface method and Lambda expression for configuration of TokenStore

Tags: java, spring, lambda, idioms, axon

I have a question on Java Syntax on lambda expressions and the [java.util.function.Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) Object. Also probably Spring Dependency Injection. It is an idiom that I don't know and I hope somebody can explain it to me. I know (probably only the basics) about that idiom of generic`@FunctionalInterface(s)` and "implementations" through lambda expressions. This use-case seems similar, but still different.

In the example, the `Function<T,R>`-Object is the Type of a parameter of a method of a configuration class with a parameter name. The argument is the lambda expression `config -> tokenStore`.

But please look at the information provided below. Here are my questions.

1. What config is passed as the argument? There is no "config" symbol there. So I guess it is injected by the Spring IoC Container.
2. And what it obviously returns is the symbol `tokenStore` that is bound to an `org.axonframework.eventhandling.tokenstore.TokenStore` Instance created by the`JpaTokenStore#build` method. There is no connection to the `config` argument. Or is there?
3. To sum it up: Just "Why?" Why are you passing a lambda expression where there is no obvious (to me) connection between the argument and the return value and why are you passing a Function-placeholder to an Interface-method - how do you call it... the head of the method? Ultimately: What is *that* doing because to someone like me who obviously doesn't know the idiom it looks like the answer is: nothing ?

So, there is this example on how to configure a `TokenStore` from the Axon Framework and I would like to understand how it works:

```
public class AxonConfig { 
    // ...
    public void registerTokenStore(EventProcessingConfigurer processingConfigurer) {
        TokenStore tokenStore = JpaTokenStore.builder()
                                             // …
                                             .build();
    
        processingConfigurer.registerTokenStore(config -> tokenStore);
    }
}
```

source: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors/streaming#token-store

And here is the source code for the [EventProcessingConfigurer#registerTokenStore (GitHub)](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/axonframework/config/EventProcessingConfigurer.java#L233) method.

```
public interface EventProcessingConfigurer {

// ...

   EventProcessingConfigurer registerTokenStore(Function<Configuration, TokenStore> tokenStore);

// ...

}
```

Incidentally, can I pass in an argument for the code block to tell the forum software which language it is?

Comment: I think you've posted this question on AxonIQ's forum, too, correct? If so, others can find it here: https://discuss.axoniq.io/t/how-does-the-configuration-of-tokenstore-work/4378

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide you some insights here, @vonSpots!

##### Question 1

The `config` symbol stands for the input parameter of the `Function`. You can name it whatever you like. Note the type of the configuration method, which expects a `Function<Configuration, TokenStore>`. The first generic in there describes the input parameter of the `Function`, thus a `Configuration` instance. The second generic describes the return value of the `Function`, which should be a `TokenStore` instance.

By using [Java's lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) notation of [input] -> [output], ending up with something called `config` seems feasible given the input type. The component in charge of providing that `config` instance, is the framework itself.

You can see this within Axon Framework's [configuration module](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/tree/master/config/src/main/java/org/axonframework/config). Lastly, it's worthwhile to note that Axon Framework does not necessitate the use of Spring at all. So, setting the `config` instance is not originating from Spring.

##### Question 2

In the provided sample, there's no connection between the input and the output. However, Axon Framework defaults to providing the entire `Configuration` object so that the user is able to retrieve Axon components from it to construct other infrastructure components.

An example of where this would be useful with the `JpaTokenStore`, is when you need to set the `Serializer`. Axon Framework will set the `Serializer` up within the `Configuration`. Hence, you can retrieve it from Axon's configuration to construct your component.

##### Question 3

Because Axon Framework does its own wiring of *all* components. You can integrate it with Spring if you like, but it does not rely on it at all. Thus, in the face of a "pure" Java configuration, you need to have some collecting component, the `Configuration`, to retrieve everything from. You could almost see it as the Application Context from Spring.

Furthermore, Axon Framework chooses to have users register lambdas instead of concrete objects to ensure components are constructed and wired in the right order.

Axon Framework has many moving components, with objects like the `CommandBus`, `EventProcessors`, `TokenStores`, and `DeadlineManager`, not forgetting to mention the Message Handling Components users wire into it themselves. By having end users provide a lambda, the framework can decide *when* to invoke the lambda.

This allows the framework to ensure all required components are in place *before* a, in your sample, `TrackingEventProcessor` can utilize the `TokenStore`.